# Converting xml to json in dataweaver mule

Tags: json, xml, mule, dataweave

I need to transform a file from xml to json. In my json file one field is a list of string which will take from Each line of xml. But I am not unale to do that in dataweaver of mule. Any help is appreciated. For reference I have posted the part of my xml and json file

XML

```
<lines>
<line id="MSK" in-voy-nbr="LP1" out-voy-nbr="LP1" />
<line id="MSC" in-voy-nbr="LP1" out-voy-nbr="LP1" />
<line id="HLC" in-voy-nbr="LP11" out-voy-nbr="" />
<line id="VIC" in-voy-nbr="LP1" out-voy-nbr="LP1" />
</lines>
```

JSON

```
{
"LINEOPERATORCODE": ["MSK", "MSC", "HLC", "VIC"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    LINEOPERATORCODE: payload.lines.*line.@id
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sulthony h. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: can u please provide me good reference of dataweave tutorial? Since I am going to extensively use this component, I should be knowing it detaily

Comment: DataWeave Reference Documentation https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation 
DataWeave Tutorial https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-tutorial 
DataWeave Examples https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-examples